# Disable specific directives after user feedback

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have a following problem. I have a number of forms done using angularjs. Now, several countries need the user to specify if the user allows to use cookies. Now, my customer wants to explicitely deactivate some directives (like registration ones) if the user selects "no cookies". I am relatively new to Angular JS, and thus do not know exactly how to do it in the "nice" way...

Comment: Show the "not nice" way, but show some attempt at solution. Otherwise, the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to decide how you want to implement this, and expand on precisely what your directive is.

If your directive is simply a custom implementation of a `<select>` element, you could simply place an `ng-disabled` parameter on it, with a parameter on it.

So, if the user clicks the checkbox and changes the value of the model associated to it (say, `$scope.allowCookies`), you might choose to implement it as follows:

```
<customSelect ng-disabled="allowCookies">
```

Depending on your implementation of the `customSelect` directive, you can define what you would like to do when the `ng-disabled` property is set to true.

Another idea would be to create an isolate scope for your directive, and map the outer scope (or some value of it) to the inner scope, like so:

```
angular.module('exampleModule', [])
.controller('exampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.allowCookies = true;
}])
.directive('custom-select', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      disabled: '=allowCookies'
    }
  };
});
```

Where `$scope.allowCookies` is mapped to the `disabled` property of the directive's isolate scope. You can read more about this [here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), and get a more in depth reference for all your directive options in the [docs.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)